# How can I display most commented or viewed post as slide

Tags: slideshow

How can I display most viewed post or most commented post as slider on my front page?

Answer (score 0):

To display "most viewed" you would need to keep a view count (which Wordpress does not do by default). They do, however, keep comment counts.

WP Beginner has articles for each of these circumstances:

- ["How to Display Popular Posts by Views in WordPress without a
  Plugin"](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-track-popular-posts-by-views-in-wordpress-without-a-plugin/)
- ["How to Display Most Commented Posts in WordPress Without a
  Plugin"](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-display-most-commented-posts-in-wordpress-without-a-plugin/)